# Clone selected folders from repo

Tags: libgit2sharp

I want to clone selected folder(s) from my repository and don't want other folders to be downloaded when cloned. I am using libgit2sharp APIv0.24.0.

[Reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0gVG.png)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot only *clone* a select set of folders, but you can only *checkout* a select set of folders.

You will need to clone the entire repository - as of now, the Git protocol has no ability to do a "narrow" clone, where you only clone a select set of files or folders.

However, you do not need to check out the entire repository.  You can ask clone to *not* do the checkout for you, then check out only the folders you are interested in.

For example:

```
string path = Repository.Clone(url, localpath, new CloneOptions()
{
    Checkout = false
});

using (var repo = new Repository(path))
{
    repo.CheckoutPaths("origin/master", new string[] { "Model" });
}
```

Comment: Thanks @edward-thomsan for your reply. Actually problem is we have developed an application which place artifacts created by our application at Client's GIT repo and we create separate folder for our application in their repo.  Some of our clients are concerning when we clone their repo and download the files which are not related to our application. Do you have any other solution for this problem?

Comment: If you are using the Git protocol, then no, there is no other solution to this problem.  If you are using a hosting provider like GitHub or Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) then you may be able to use their REST API or client libraries, but this is not something that can be done with LibGit2Sharp or the git command-line.

Comment: Thanks @edward-thomsan for your help